# Why am I seeing InvalidInstanceID.Malformed in my NAT Gateway's Route?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-nat-gateway

I am trying to create a Stack using AWS CDK (in Javascript). In my stack, I would like to create a NAT gateway in a public subnet that is referenced by Route Table in my private subnet. Pretty standard stuff.

Below is a snippet of the relevant code I have to create the infra for this

```
// CREATE VPC & SUBNET
const vpc = new ec2.CfnVPC(this, `${applicationName}-vpc`, {
  cidrBlock: '10.1.0.0/16',
})

const publicSubnet1 = new ec2.PublicSubnet(this, `${applicationName}-public1`, {
  availabilityZone: availabilityZone1,
  cidrBlock: '10.1.0.0/20',
  vpcId: vpc.attrVpcId,
  mapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
})

// CREATE NAT GATEWAY
const webserverNatGatewayEIP = new ec2.CfnEIP(this, `${applicationName}-webserver-natgwEIP`)

const webserverNatGateway = new ec2.CfnNatGateway(this, `${applicationName}-webserver-natgw`, {
  subnetId: publicSubnet1.subnetId,
  allocationId: webserverNatGatewayEIP.attrAllocationId,
  tags: [{
    key: 'Name',
    value: `${applicationName}-webserver-natgw`
  }]
})
```

This is fine. However, when I try to create my route table and a route to that NAT gateway as follows:

```
// CREATE PRIVATE ROUTE TABLE
const webserverRouteTable = new ec2.CfnRouteTable(this, `${applicationName}-webserver-rtb`, {
  vpcId: vpc.attrVpcId
})

// not working, need to debug
const webserverRouteTableNatGWRoute = new ec2.CfnRoute(this, 'webserver-rt-natgw-route', {
  routeTableId: webserverRouteTable.attrRouteTableId,
  destinationCidrBlock: '0.0.0.0/0',
  instanceId: webserverNatGateway.attrNatGatewayId
})
```

I am seeing the following error message when I try to deploy my stack.

```
Invalid id: "nat-0cfe60af88b3df93a" (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidInstanceID.Malformed; Request
ID: 4ecbe914-6ead-4d05-bf8c-d87cd0c72654; Proxy: null)
```

I don't understand how the `.attrXYZ` call for instanceId could be malformed. I am using all over the rest of my infra and it has been working just fine as similar arguments.

I manually checked via the AWS console to see if that NAT Gateway id was incorrect, and it matches perfectly. I don't see why this is failing. I guessed perhaps that maybe the NAT gateway wasn't being created in time, so I added a dependency on it via

`webserverRouteTableNatGWRoute.addDependency(webserverNatGateway)`

but that didn't fix the error. Any ideas?

Comment: is there a reason you're not using using the `PRIVATE_WITH_NAT` subnet type when creating the VPC? That takes care of all that you're doing right now. [Vpc construct docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ec2.Vpc.html) & SubnetType [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ec2.Subnet.html)

Comment: I was trying it that way instead of just doing everything with CFNs', but I got frustrated that I couldn't share route tables between subnets by default. Now that I think of it, I guess I can just manually provision new route tables and manually assign a common one to the sharing subnets. I will try that, thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question directly, it is because the `instanceId` prop is for an EC2 instance ID. To point it to a NAT gateway, you need to pass the gateway ID to the `natGatewayId` prop instead.

Like so:

```
const webserverRouteTableNatGWRoute = new ec2.CfnRoute(this, 'webserver-rt-natgw-route', {
  routeTableId: webserverRouteTable.attrRouteTableId,
  destinationCidrBlock: '0.0.0.0/0',
  natGatewayId: webserverNatGateway.attrNatGatewayId // different prop name
})
```

Comment: I read "NAT Instance" on the docs and mixed it with "NAT Gateway". Thank you very much!